# Select value from mixed-type row in KDB

Tags: kdb, q-lang

We defined our KDB table with the type C (i.e. Character array). The first value which we inserted had a type String.  The second value had a type int (i.e. i). Now, when we try to query KDB with conditions `where like="value"` it doesn't work. Because we have mixed type in one column, how can we query data and filter it (use in `where` clause) based on this column?

Comment: can you provide a simple example of ur table and query u r using. That will help  to clearly understand your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I almost don't want to give a solution here because mixing strings with integers in a single column is a terrible idea. Completely destroys performance and prevents any of the benefits that kdb offers.

First and foremost, re-think your setup.

If you insist on keeping it as is, you can query it like this:

```
tab:([] col1:`a`b`c;col2:1 2 3;col3:("foo";"bar";1i))
```

For exact matching

```
q)select from tab where col3~\:"foo"
col1 col2 col3
---------------
a    1    "foo"

q)select from tab where col3~\:1i
col1 col2 col3
--------------
c    3    1
```

For regex matching

```
q)select from tab where {$[10h=type x;x like "f*";0b]}'[col3]
col1 col2 col3
---------------
a    1    "foo"
```

But don't say you weren't warned or advised against!

Answer (score 0):

As @terrylynch said, you should avoid mixing types in columns. You will lose a lot of speed and make your life a living hell if you do this. I would say the first thing you should do is inspect the way your intaking data (and what that data is like). Sounds like you  might want to represent your data differently.